# Middleman blog paths issue

Tags: path, blogs, middleman

I've recently published a blog with Middleman on GitHub pages and while the index page works fine (mathesond2.github.io/learnt/), whenever I choose a post, I get a 404. This is because the url path is at:

http://mathesond2.github.io/blog/2013/09/02/first-post.html

Instead of:
http://mathesond2.github.io/**learnt/**blog/2013/09/02/first-post.html

I've gone into `config.rb` to change the `blog.prefix` from `/blog` to `/learnt/blog` but still see no difference. Any suggestions?

Thanks,
David

Comment: Can you post your `config.rb` and your `config.ru`?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on my blog. In my config.rb I changed the site_url setting to point at the full url for my blog e.g. 
`set :site_url, 'http://www.gerardcondon.com/chess'`

Maybe setting `set :site_url, 'http://mathesond2.github.io/learnt'` would work for you?